# how one can scan command output of any program/process to ensure it's success/failure string exists in console using python

Tags: python

In python how one can scan command output of any program/process to ensure it's success/failure string exists in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more reliable way to do this is to check the process return code (as has already been mentioned) but you could do it this way:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/somejavaprogram -flag1 arg1".split())
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
if (proc.returncode = 0 and
    "data successfully processed" in stdout):
    print "Handle success here!"
else:
    print "Job failed with return code %s"%(proc.returncode)
    print stderr
```

Of course the above assumes a well behaved process that writes errors to stderr and has a 0 return code when it runs successfully. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you Mike. This is helpful. I'm trying to write generic function in python which will take 3 parameter(directory where command  needs to execte(/a/b/c, application command(java or python) with bunch of parameters, Success message(like, data processed correctly)

Comment: example of command: /a/b/c java -jar blabla.jar --parameter 1 --parameter 2 "data processed successfully"

Answer (score 2):

Normally success should be determined from the process's return code, not the output it generates. But if you *insist* on looking at the output then see the `stderr` argument of the various functions in [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: lets say, if I'm executing some java program and at end of execution I need to know success message, such as "data successfully processed" exists in output console.

Comment: You may need to look at `stdout`. But that depends on how the program works.